# "Cannot find name 'import'" Auto-imports not working with Typescript in Nuxt3

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, gsap, nuxt3

### Overview

I'm having a couple issues with imports not working as expected in my simple Nuxt3 website.

I'm getting different behaviors on my imports when I have the script tag set to `<script setup lang='ts'>` and when I just have `<script setup>` as well as different behaviors in different components.

Below are the examples where I'm getting unexpected behavior. I'm just learning Nuxt3 (and relatively inexperienced with typescript too). Here are my questions:

1. Why in Example 1 can it not find gsap or ScrollToPlugin when using typescript, but it finds them when not? Searching around I've seen that the gsap library includes its type declarations as well.
2. Why does onMounted in Example 1 work as an auto-import with typescript, while it does not in Example 3?
3. Why are ref and onMounted not auto-imported with typescript in Example 3. I'm not sure that 'watch' is auto-imported, but I know ref, computed and lifecycle hooks are.

Any ideas or explanations are greatly appreciated!

### Examples

#### 1. Contact page with typescript

Error: "Cannot find module 'gsap' or it's corresponding type declarations"
Same for 'gsap/ScrollToPlugin'

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import gsap from 'gsap'
import { ScrollToPlugin } from 'gsap/ScrollToPlugin'

onMounted(() => {
  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollToPlugin)
})

const smoothScrollToElement = () => {
  console.log('scroll')
  gsap.to(window, {
    duration: 1,
    scrollTo: {
      y: '#contactForm',
      offsetY: 150,
    },
  })
}
</script>
```

#### 2. Contact page without typescript

No errors, works great

```js
<script setup>
import gsap from 'gsap'
import { ScrollToPlugin } from 'gsap/ScrollToPlugin'

onMounted(() => {
  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollToPlugin)
})

const smoothScrollToElement = () => {
  console.log('scroll')
  gsap.to(window, {
    duration: 1,
    scrollTo: {
      y: '#contactForm',
      offsetY: 150,
    },
  })
}
</script>
```

#### 3. Iframe page with typescript and auto-imports

Error: "Cannot find name 'ref'"
Same for 'onMounted' and 'watch'

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
let loading = ref(true)
let checkForIframe = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  checkForIframe = setInterval(() => {
    const iframeEl = document.querySelector('.oc_shingle_view iframe')
    if (iframeEl) loading.value = false
  }, 1000)
})

watch(loading, async (newLoading, oldLoading) => {
  if (oldLoading === false)
    clearInterval(checkForIframe)
})
</script>
```

#### 4. Iframe page with typescript and manual imports

No errors, works great

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch, onMounted } from 'vue'
let loading = ref(true)
let checkForIframe = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  checkForIframe = setInterval(() => {
    const iframeEl = document.querySelector('.oc_shingle_view iframe')
    if (iframeEl) loading.value = false
  }, 1000)
})

watch(loading, async (newLoading, oldLoading) => {
  if (oldLoading === false)
    clearInterval(checkForIframe)
})
</script>
```